colors not working on default terminal for release rust exe
I use tracing and tracing-subscriber for logging. It uses colour codes, which works in windows terminal and the vscode terminal. However, the terminal that opens when double-clicking the built exe doesn't like the colours.
This is confusing because my program invokes fzf which is successfully printing coloured text at the bottom, so this terminal does support colours it's just not working for tracing?

tracing = "0.1.40"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3.18" }


Note that on Windows 11 you can configure the default terminal to be the new Windows Terminal.

This answer helpfully recommends looking into SetConsoleMode
We can use this to fix things.
#[cfg(windows)]
mod windows_ansi {
    use windows::core::Result;
    use windows::Win32::Foundation::HANDLE;
    use windows::Win32::System::Console::GetConsoleMode;
    use windows::Win32::System::Console::GetStdHandle;
    use windows::Win32::System::Console::SetConsoleMode;
    use windows::Win32::System::Console::ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    use windows::Win32::System::Console::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE;

    pub fn enable_ansi_support() -> Result<()> {
        unsafe {
            let handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)?;
            if handle == HANDLE::default() {
                return Err(windows::core::Error::from_win32());
            }

            let mut mode = std::mem::zeroed();
            GetConsoleMode(handle, &mut mode)?;
            SetConsoleMode(handle, mode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING)?;
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // start logging
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();

    // fix colours in the default exe terminal
    // show no errors when colours unavailable (piping situations)
    #[cfg(windows)]
    let _ = windows_ansi::enable_ansi_support();

    info!("Ahoy!");
    Ok(())
}

[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
windows = { version = "0.58.0", features = [
    "Win32",
    "Win32_System",
    "Win32_System_Console",
] }


Some other links I found:

https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/l9ftyi/with_tracing_the_colored_logging_output_not_work/
How to avoid text coloring when using tracing-appender?
I cannot print color escape codes to the terminal

